# MySQL formatting and math on currency with a precision greater than 2dp

Tags: mysql, math, currency, currency-formatting

I am looking for a correct format and do math on currency in MySQL where the prices are dynamically calculated and as such, have a precision greater than 2dp.

```
calculated unit Price = 1.255
displayed price       = 1.26
```

If a customer orders 100 of the product:

```
actual total (100 * 1.255)   = 125.50
displayed total (100 * 1.26) = 126.00
```

So, If a customer looks at their invoice, and does the maths, they will see that they have been under charged by 50p because I will be charging them £125.50 but they will do the math for themselves and think that they should have been charged £126.00.

I think that the easiest way of tackling this problem is to *truncate* or *round* the calculated unit price like `ROUND(1.255, 2)` or `TRUNCATE(1.255, 2)` meaning that the display and the accounts will match up.

This is not a problem for very small quantities, however it does become significant when the customer orders more units.

The problem is that I don't want to charge the customer £125.00 or £126.00 I want to charge them £125.50 for 100 items.

Any ideas or should I simply display the price to the customer in 3dp, not 2dp, but round the total?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By rounding the unit price, you are destroying information.  The only way to solve this is, as you suggest, to display unit prices to the customer in full.